# Typeerror:list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have got error in type of the Indices.
I tried to run the code it got complied but the Error you can see in Python IDLE below.

The Code:

```
def triples(self, (sub, pred, obj)):

    #Generator over the triple store.
    #Returns triples that match the given triple pattern. 

    # check which terms are present in order to use the correct index:
    try:
        if sub != None: 
            if pred != None:
                # sub pred obj
                if obj != None:
                    if obj in self._spo[sub][pred]: yield (sub, pred, obj)
                # sub pred None
                else:
                    for retObj in self._spo[sub][pred]: yield (sub, pred, retObj)
            else:
                # sub None obj
                if obj != None:
                    for retPred in self._osp[obj][sub]: yield (sub, retPred, obj)
                # sub None None
                else:
                    for retPred, objSet in self._spo[sub].items():
                        for retObj in objSet:
                            yield (sub, retPred, retObj)
        else:
            if pred != None:
                # None pred obj
                if obj != None:
                    for retSub in self._pos[pred][obj]:
                        yield (retSub, pred, obj)
                # None pred None
                else:
                    for retObj, subSet in self._pos[pred].items():
                        for retSub in subSet:
                            yield (retSub, pred, retObj)
            else:
                # None None obj
                if obj != None:
                    for retSub, predSet in self._osp[obj].items():
                        for retPred in predSet:
                            yield (retSub, retPred, obj)
                # None None None
                else:
                    for retSub, predSet in self._spo.items():
                        for retPred, objSet in predSet.items():
                            for retObj in objSet:
                                yield (retSub, retPred, retObj)
    # KeyErrors occur if a query term wasn't in the index, so we yield nothing:
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

The following error after executing in Python IDLE. The Error I got thought Indices in Python IDLE.

list(movie_graph.triples(("blade_runner","directed_by",None))) [("blade_runner","directed_by","ridle_scott")]

Traceback (most recent call last)
     File "", line 1, in 
    list(movie_graph.triples(("blade_runner","directed_by",None)))[("blade_runner","directed_by","ridle_scott")]
 TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is unrelated to the `triples` function. This line in itself is erroneous:

```
list(movie_graph.triples(("blade_runner","directed_by",None))) [("blade_runner","directed_by","ridle_scott")]
```

`list(...)` returns a list, and the following square brackets, `[...]`, are attempting to index that list. A list index must be an integer, not `("blade_runner","directed_by","ridle_scott")`, which is a tuple, hence the error you are seeing.

It's hard to see exactly what you are trying to achieve, but that's why you're seeing that error.